# how do i write a sql query to select the names that may contain any one of the vowels?

Tags: mysql

I m trying to query a database with about 2000 entries. I want to select the entries in which the names may contain any one of the vowel.

I tried using the following query, but it gives me those entries that contain all the given characters in that order.

```
select * from myTable where name like '%a%e%i%';
```

How do I modify the above query to select those entries with names that may contain at least anyone of the vowels.

Comment: mysql <> sql-server. which one are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I hope this helps you...**

```
 SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE name REGEXP 'a|e';
 or.....
 SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE name REGEXP 'a|e|i';
```

Comment: thanks :) can u tel me how to select names that doesnt contain any of these vowels.. i mean the not of this case?

Comment: SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` NOT REGEXP 'a|e|i'

Answer (score 3):

Try this for SQL Server:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE name LIKE '%[AEIOU]%';
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, you would do:

```
where name like '%[aeiou]%';
```

In MySQL, you would do something similar with a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

Use `OR` like this.

This will work for both SQL Server and MySql.

```
select * from myTable where name like '%a%' OR name like '%e%' OR name like '%i%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `LIKE` and `OR`.

**Query**

```
select * from myTable
where name like '%a%'
or name like '%e%'
or name like '%i%'
or name like '%o%'
or name like '%u%'
```